# Servlet forward in filter give unexpect result

Tags: java, servlets

In my filter I would like to filter a request from "/a/b/c" to "/index.html", I use:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").include(request, response);
```

It works but after forwarding the request to `index.html`, the client request wrong js and css path in index.html:

For example it requests `/a/b/c/css/bootstrap.min.css` but should be `/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

What I want to do is just forward requesting to `/a/b/c` to `index.html`, without changing the request path of other resources. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the path in your JSPs relative to the web context root, so they would not depend on the current page URL.

```
<c:set var="context" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<script src="${context}/themes/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Also, why don't you do a redirect instead of servlet filter? Or maybe have several controllers with the same view?

Comment: Your way works, for some reason I have to use forward. Thanks